# Does “disheartening” have sadder connotations than “discouraging”?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Let’s say someone has a sibling whose company they enjoy, but this sibling is really bad at keeping in touch, and if it weren’t for the effort this person put in, they would only ever see the sibling at family gatherings. Eventually the person decides to stop trying, since the effort is never returned.

Now of course you could say that the person found the lack of investment from the sibling ***discouraging*** and thus changed their own behavior, but would “***disheartening***” be an even better suited word, since they also feel rejected by the sibling? Or is that distinction between the two words something I made up in my head?

Also, as I don’t live in an English speaking country: is “disheartening” a normal/common word in everyday language or is it a little old-fashioned/formal?

Comment: In my opinion disheartening is quite formal in the US, I only really ever see it written.

Answer (score 2):

Your intuitions about these words match the common native speakers' usage.

As very close synonyms, on the strength of sadness, 'disheartening' is a little more sad than 'discouraging'. There's a little extra nuance of despair possibly with the connotations of 'heart' connected with emotions. 'Discourage' is in that same direction, but just not as far.

I really can't say that one is better or worse for your situation, that's up to your own inner feelings. But for the community of users of English, 'disheartening' is a little more sad than 'discourage'.

As to frequency of use and formality, 'disheartening' is not as common as 'discouraging' ([in print, from a fifth to a third of the frequency of discouraging](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=disheartening%2C+discouraging&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3)). I'd consider 'disheartening' somewhat more formal (or instead educated, which is not necessarily the same thing) than 'discouraging' (I can imagine a football coach using 'discouraging' a little more than 'disheartening', but the neither by the players.